# What does 7c mean in this poster?

Tags: schitts-creek

What does 7c mean in this poster? 
I know it is related to time.

[image]

Comment: [Related](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/15174/what-does-8-7c-mean)

Comment: [Also related](https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/f7/51/96/f75196b5b5fcb65c53f286c15837e555.jpg)

Comment: I like how the question only asks about the C, but there's a bunch of debate about the P in the answers... lol

Comment: @jpmc26. The first time I ever saw am & pm abbreviated to a & p was in JFK Airport. I'm used to seeing transport schedules in 24-hour time. Seeing them in 12-hour, and further abbreviated in a fashion I'd never seen before, was confusing. The USA really does make no concessions to tourists or other international visitors, even in their major international transport hubs. Strange country.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

No.  The "P" means "8 P.M." (evening) Eastern Time (implied) and "7 p.m. Central".  The P does NOT mean Pacific time.  8 p.m. Pacific time is 11 p.m. on the East coast.

A live broadcast (or taped show that goes out on air) at 8 p.m. Eastern Time would be seen at 7 p.m. if you lived in Central time zone.  That's why it is advertised this way, presumably somewhere on the East coast of the U.S.

"P" is a trendy abbreviation for P.M.

Comment: This was my initial thought, then I fixed it to Pacific, thinking *that* was wrong. But there's also [tape-delay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effects_of_time_zones_on_North_American_broadcasting#Time_zone_feeds), so now I don't know *what* to think.

Comment: See the Schitt's Creek schedule in the bottom of [this page](http://www.nytimes.com/2015/02/11/arts/television/review-in-schitts-creek-a-spoiled-little-rich-family-starts-over.html?_r=0), for example, where there's a *1* hour difference between Pacific and Central, not **3**.

Comment: @Walt it says `Pop, Wednesday nights at 10, Eastern and Pacific times; 9, Central time.` So both East and West at 10pm, making it even weirder.

Comment: Even weirder. Looked at Pop's schedule for today. 9 East, 8 central, 10 Pacific

Comment: Yeah, this is a mess. I was barely even aware of Pop, which doesn't help. If anyone has a definitive answer, I'd be glad to hear it. (Oddly enough, the OP didn't even *ask* about the P).

Comment: is Pop a US channel? If not, perhaps it's a Quebec abbreviation? Schitt's Creek is a Canadian show...

Comment: @cde, I don't see that.  For 3.17, it shows 9East/8Central/7Mountain (all watching the East Coast feed).  For Pacific time, it shows 9 again (not 10).  Makes sense if they have a separate (3-hour delay) west coast feed.

Comment: @BowlOfRed i used http://www.locatetv.com/listings/tv-guide-network and used NYC, Beverly hills, and Wichita as the areas.

Comment: @cde, I'm looking at their direct schedule: http://poptv.com/schedule

Comment: @KateGregory POP is LA based, and used be known as TV Guide.

Comment: The reality is that central is just weird... Every other time zone uses the same time for their shows but everything in Central is an hour early.

Comment: @catija, Mountain time stations are almost never with East Coast time either.  However it's hit or miss if they're getting a direct feed (East-2 hour local, most cable networks) or a 1-hour delay feed (East-1 hour local, same local time as Central, most broadcast networks).  As there are many fewer Mountain time viewers, it's often not advertised nationally either way.

Comment: @BowlOfRed Um... no.  If it's not live TV like sports or award shows it's generally aired at the same local time in all time zones **except** Central. So, NCIS is aired at 8PM in Eastern, Mountain, and Pacific but is aired at 7 PM in Central time. So, on one of these images, it would say 8/7C meaning it's at 8PM everywhere but it's at 7 PM in Central.

Comment: Mountain time zone is the red-headed stepchild of TV schedules.  Any time from 6pm to 9pm is possible for Mountain time...

Comment: You'd think `TONIGHT` would be the big giveaway that the time is going to be PM....American TV is weird.

Comment: Question: " I know it is related to time. " Answer: "No. The 'P' means '8 P.M.'...." Okay....? What is the "no" for?

Answer (score 11):

Actually, in this promo poster, the 8P 7C means: Broadcasts 8:00**pm** (Eastern time by default), 7:00pm Central Time (since Central Time is an hour behind Eastern). P = p.m., C = Central Time.

Comment: It's not Eastern by default... it's **every** time zone except Central.

Comment: @Catija Well, it's commonly "8:00PM Eastern and Pacific".  As someone who lived in the mountain time zone for years, they often followed the Central time zone if you were on the east side of the time zone (particularly if your broadcast stations reached into the central time zone).  Though the west half of the Mountain time zone either showed it at 8:00PM, or even at 9:00PM to match the Pacific time zone...

Answer (score 5):

Looking at [the POP schedule page](http://poptv.com/schedule), one can see that they use P to mean PM.  And on the homepage right now there's an ad for the show saying it's on at "8/7C".  Hmmm, they left out the P completely?!  (Maybe they saw this question.)

More revealing is a look at [a news item for the season premiere in question](http://www.broadwayworld.com/bwwtv/article/Season-Two-of-SCHITTS-CREEK-to-Premiere-on-Pop-Today-20160315), which says,

> Small town living continues for the Rose family in the season two
>   premiere of SCHITT'S CREEK on Pop today, March 16, 2016 at 8:00 PM,
>   ET/PT

-- meaning, the show is at 8 PM *both* in the Eastern Time and Pacific Time zones.  (From growing up in ET, I know that networks tend to combine the ET/CT areas.  So, 7 PM Central Time fits also.)

Conclusion: **Everyone is right!  P means both PM *and* Pacific Time** and C means Central Time.

(Whew, glad we figured that out.  Now, has anyone noticed the casual way the guy's holding his jumper cables?  Could end up with a thumb welded to a clamp, or something...)

Comment: And no one cares about Mountain Time.

Comment: @Catija - I've never understood this myself - surely people living in the Central time zone are well aware that national TV broadcasts are given in Eastern Time and they've got to subtract an hour?  The Mountain time zone people can figure it out .... I grew up in Pacific Time and was able to figure out on my own that if I was listening to a radio program at 9PM that was listed for 9PM there was no point in calling in ...

Comment: @davidbak Well, there's a difference... if it's **live** TV like sports or award shows that's one thing. But non-live TV is aired at the same local time in all time zones **except** Central. So, NCIS is aired at 8PM in Eastern, Mountain, and Pacific but is aired at 7 PM in Central time.

Comment: @Catija - really, Mountain too?  I thought there were only two feeds, east coast and west coast?

Comment: @davidbak It may depend on the network. I definitely checked the broadcast schedule for Colorado Springs and NCIS **does** air at 8pm there.

Comment: @davidbak The border region of Eastern and Central time is much more densely populated than either border of the Mountain time zone, so there would inevitably be people on one side who get their TV service from stations on the other side.